# How to clear angular warning messages while installing packages using NPM

Tags: angular, npm, warnings

I need to remove below warning message of Angular while I am installing the packages.

```
npm WARN @auth0/angular-jwt@5.0.2 requires a peer of @angular/common@>=9.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN angular2-notifications@9.0.0 requires a peer of @angular/animations@^9.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN angular2-notifications@9.0.0 requires a peer of @angular/common@^9.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN angular2-notifications@9.0.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@^9.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN angular2-notifications@9.0.0 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser@^9.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN angular2-notifications@9.0.0 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@^9.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN angular2-notifications@9.0.0 requires a peer of rxjs@^6.5.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN angular2-notifications@9.0.0 requires a peer of zone.js@^0.10.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ng-file-drop@5.0.2 requires a peer of @angular/common@^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ng-file-drop@5.0.2 requires a peer of @angular/core@^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ng-file-drop@5.0.2 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser@^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ng-file-drop@5.0.2 requires a peer of rxjs@^5.5.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ngx-mat-select-search@3.3.0 requires a peer of @angular/material@^8.0.0 || ^9.0.0 || ^10.0.0 || ^11.0.0 || ^12.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

These are the warning messages coming while installing the packages using `npm`. My `package.json` file is given below.

> package.json:

```
{
  "name": "demo",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^7.2.16",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.16",
    "@angular/material": "^7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.2.0",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^5.0.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.12.1",
    "ag-grid": "^18.1.2",
    "ag-grid-angular": "^22.1.1",
    "ag-grid-community": "^22.1.1",
    "angular-font-awesome": "^3.1.2",
    "angular-popper": "^2.0.1",
    "angular2-notifications": "^9.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.2",
    "bootstrap.min.js": "^3.3.5",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.2",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "ngx-mat-select-search": "^3.3.0",
    "ngx-monaco-editor": "^6.0.0",
    "ngx-spinner": "^7.2.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zlib": "^1.0.5",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.13.9",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.3.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.2.0",
    "@cisco-ngx/cui-components": "^7.14.22",
    "@cisco-ngx/cui-pipes": "^7.14.22",
    "@cisco-ngx/cui-services": "^7.14.22",
    "@cisco-ngx/cui-utils": "^7.14.22",
    "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.33",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "cisco-ui": "^1.3.3",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "luxon": "^1.25.0",
    "ng-file-drop": "^5.0.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslerp2": "^2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.2.2"
  }
}
```

Here I want to clear all the warning messages. Can anybody suggest me what should be the correct approach to resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

npm no longer installs peer dependencies automatically. So you need to do that
by yourself, installing each dependency separately:

```
npm install --save-dev <dependency-name>
```

Comment: Is it like `npm install -save-dev angular2-notifications` ?

Comment: No. This one you already have installed, you need to install peer dependencies of it. Like: `npm install --save-dev @angular/animations@^9.0.0`

Comment: Ok I will try same.

Comment: No this solution working as expected.